# Can a Kohen Marry a Woman with a Non-Jewish Father?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, marriage, kohen-priest

Is a Kohen allowed to marry a woman who is the daughter of a Jewish woman and non-Jewish man?

Answer (score 18):

According to [Shulchan Aruch, Even Ha'Ezer 7:17 and commentaries there](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40524&st=&pgnum=43), they should not marry. However, if they did so, they may remain together and need not divorce.

Comment: Does the Cohen lose any Cohanic privileges? I would assume not, or else the commentaries would have said something.

Comment: @Menachem: that, plus anyway I don't think he loses Kohanic privileges for something like this which is just *pegam* but not an outright issur.

Comment: @Menachem The better question is whether his sons with this woman are Cohanim.

Comment: @sah why is that question better?

Comment: Having learned more, I'm quite sure that in this case and only this case, the sons are cohanim and the father doesn't lose his privileges. @Menachem

Comment: @SAH: Can you elaborate? What led you to this conclusion?

Comment: @Menachem I am in the category in question (though not engaged to a kohen, and don't plan to be) so took it upon myself to learn. I can't name a specific source; have seen and heard it in many places

Comment: @SAH Since they do not require him to divorce, but do require him to divorce a divorcee, then the implication is that the children are kohanim. If the children were chalalim (as with a divorcee) he would have been required to divorce her.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is disputed both in the Gemara and in the Rishonim. The ruling of the commentators of the Shulchan Aruch is that lechatchila a kohen should not marry her, but if he did marry her he is not required to divorce her.
There have been cases where authorities have been lenient that even if a kohen was only engaged to her, he may marry her.

Answer (score 2):

For further discussion about whether a Beit Din may sign off/administer the wedding, see the Machloket between Rav Moshe Feinstein (Iggerot Moshe Even HaEzer vol 1 Siman 5), who forbade it, and Rav Shalom Meshash (Shemesh U’Magen vol. 3 Even HaEzer 58) and Rav Shlomo Amar (Shema Shlomo vol. 5 Even HaEzer 8), who permitted it, as discussed in by [Rav J.D. Bleich](http://traditionarchive.org/news/_pdfs/71-77%20Bleich.pdf), [Rav Elyashiv Knohl](http://www.tzohar.org.il/?p=5776), a [Beit Din in Haifa](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/psk/psk.asp?id=624), and [Rav Howard Jachter](https://www.jewishlinknj.com/features/20041-rav-shlomo-amar-visiting-shaarei-orah-in-teaneck-this-shabbat). Rav Ovadia in later years was mattir outright based on a double Safek: whether he's really a kohen or not and if the Halacha follows the Rishonim and Shulchan Aruch who hold a Bat Nochri is pegumah or like those who disagree. (Yabia Omer vol. 11 Even HaEzer 34)