# Mamzer from non-Jew

Tags: halacha, gentiles, marriage, mamzer, arayot

If a Jewess married to a Jew has a child from a non-Jew is that child a [mamzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamzer)?

Is there agreement amongst the poskim about this?

Comment: strongly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1348/759

Comment: מחלוקת רבינו תם וריב"ם בתוספות ביבמות

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know about modern poskim, but the Shulchan Aruch ([Even HaEzer 4:19](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9727&st=&pgnum=30)) rules that the child of a gentile and a Jewess *independent of her marital status* is not a mamzer but is disqualified from marrying a kohein (kohanim in general have stricter strictures restricting marriage). None of the standard commentaries there seem to disagree.

Comment: I have translated 'pagum' as 'disqualified' although the level of disqualification is not clear. For our purposes I think this suffices. As usual CYLOR if necessary.

Comment: @Vram I thought the Halacha is we don't believe a woman to say that she cheated on her husband because we suspect she is simply lying to attain a divorce.

Comment: I love this: "stricter strictures restricting".

Comment: @SethJ http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15191/microwave-on-pesach#comment29531_15192

Comment: Don't we say that be'ilas akum is like a be'ilas behaima, therefor the child is not a mamzer?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Double AA wrote in their answer, that is absolutely the view of modern poskim as well. Rav Ephraim Oshry has a thorough and moving teshuvah about it Shut Mimaamakim 2:24.

As an aside, the subsequent teshuvah (2:25) deals with whether such a person requires a conversion. I was surprised when I first read it that the question was not 100% black and white and there are opinions that such a person is not automatically Jewish. Rav Oshry concludes the overwhelming majority and correct approach is that such a person does not require conversion but it would be prudent to do one "just in case" and to avoid all doubt. (As far as I am aware, most rabbis today do not even do a "just in case" conversion, and I'm pretty familiar with inyanei gerut and "half Jews." Perhaps this is a result of greater community acceptance and/or emotional sensitivities of the people involved.).

Comment: If the mother is Jewish, the child would not nee geirus.

Comment: @KovyJacob if you read my answer and the teshuvah I cite you will see that there are minority opinions to the contrary. I was as surprised as you are.

Comment: The gemara paskins that the child is 100% Jewish in that case...

Comment: There is a machlokes, and the gemara paskins not like the man di'amar who says that the child isn't Jewish.

Comment: Take it up with the Acharonim. See for yourself here. https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22145&st=&pgnum=159 See also Tosafot Bava Batra 149b Rebbi Mari  Yearos Dvash Derush 17,Pischeiy Teshuvah E.H. 4/1; Avnei Nezer Even HaEzer 16 (describing the shita of Tosafot); Maharm Shik EH 20. Also see note 4 of this website bringing some of those sources. https://shulchanaruchharav.com/who-is-a-jew-verifying-ones-claims-of-jewishness/

Comment: I will. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I posted that before that comment from you popped up.