# If a woman converts to Judaism while pregnant, will her child be eligible to marry a Kohen?

Tags: halacha, marriage, kohen-priest, conversion-to-judaism, pregnancy-birth

If a woman converts to Judaism while pregnant, will her child be eligible to marry a Kohen?

Case #1 -- Assume her husband is a Jew by birth.

Case #2 -- Assume her husband converted to Judaism prior to the child's conception. (I [know](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14231/1244) the kohanim have assumed an extra stringency against marrying the child of two converts. However, would there be a *Biblical* prohibition in the case I describe?)

Case #3 -- Assume her husband was a non-Jew at the time of conception. (Again, would there be a Biblical prohibition? --I know there would be rabbinical prohibitions as discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14111/1244).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rambam writes ([Issurei Biah 19:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/5119.htm#10)) regarding the case of two converts who married each other and had a child who went and married a kohein:

> ואם נשאת: לא תצא, הואיל והורתה ולידתה בקדושה
>   And if they did get married, they need not get divorced since her conception and birth were in holiness [ie. of a Jewish mother].

This implies strongly that if both the conception and the birth were not "in Holiness," than the child would be forced to divorce her kohein husband, the general indicator of a biblically forbidden marriage. This understanding of the Rambam is found in both the Beit Shemuel (sk 42) and the Chelkat Mechokek (sk 29) to [Shulchan Aruch Even HaEzer Siman 7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40524&st=&pgnum=44).

It seems they are all agreeing that this child is considered a full-fledged convert in her own right, which would make her biblically forbidden to a kohein independent of her father's status. The other discussions you reference in your question are talking about cases where the mother was already Jewish when the child was conceived[.](http://www.google.com/)