# May a Kohen marry a giyores?

Tags: halacha, marriage, conversion-to-judaism, kohen-priest

Is it permissible for a Kohen to marry a giyores (convert)?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14228

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. ([Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer 6:8](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%95#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.97))

Answer (score -5):

A regular aged giyores, [no](http://judaism.about.com/od/jewishweddingsmarriage/f/cohen_convt.htm).

There is a possibility,however, that perhaps this is due to the talmudic assumption that all non-Jews above the age of 3 are not virgins. The halacha might change with regard to a giyores who converted as an infant.

I think  that possibility is raised in [Yebamoth 60b](http://halakhah.com/yebamoth/yebamoth_60.html) but I do not know the final halacha.

Comment: I know it's an opinion in the gemara, but it's pretty clearly rejected lemaaseh by Rambam and Shulchan Aruch. Would you quote Beit Shamai as a possibility?

Comment: As I said before, "I do not know the final halacha".

Comment: See the paragraph linked to in the other answer. It says "אפילו נתגיירה ונשתחררה פחותה מבת שלש שנים הואיל ואינה בת ישראל הרי זו זונה ואסורה לכהן" ("even if she converted... under three years old, since she's not a daughter of Israel, she is a _zona_ and forbidden to a _kohen_"). Has "I do not know the final halacha" changed?

Comment: at the time I wrote it, I did not.

Comment: @ClintEastwood That's why you can [edit]!

Comment: ... or delete your post, if you prefer to. In this case, though, I think it may be valuable to have an answer specify that a _kohen_ is barred from marrying even someone who converted young, so people (like you and me) who thought otherwise are disillusioned.