# Is the son of a non-Jewish father a mamzer?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mamzer

Is someone has a non-Jewish father but a Jewish mother, this obviously makes them a Jew. But does it make them a mamzer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The halacha is that he is not a mamzer.

See Yebamot 16b:

> On account of the slaves of Solomon,' the reason is quite intelligible, because  **he may hold the opinion that the child of a heathen or a slave who had intercourse with a daughter in Israel is a bastard.**

23a:

> Said Rabina: From this it follows that the 'son of your daughter' who derives from a heathen is called 'thy son'.
> Does this imply that Rabina is of the opinion that if a heathen or a slave had intercourse with a daughter of Israel the child i considered fit! -Though he is admittedly no bastard neither is he considered fit; he is rather regarded as a tainted Israelite.

45b:

> **And the law is that if an idolater or a slave had cohabited with the daughter of an Israelite the child [bor from such a union] is legitimate, both in the case of a married, and in that of an unmarried woman.**

SA EH 4, 19:

> עובד כוכבים ועבד....  ואם באו על בת ישראל, בין פנויה בין אשת איש, הולד כשר, ופגום לכהונה:‏
>
> NJ or slave...  if they had relationship with a Jewish woman,  celibate or married,  the child is Kasher,  but not for marriage with a Kohen (the daughter)*

---

- see [this post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71010/9215)  for the last rule and for a little more extended explanation.